# Bootstrap and Vertical Text - Cannot Get it to Work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I am not having any luck with vertical text mixed with bootstrap.  I am trying to also vertical align the text in the div too once I get this working.  The best way to explain it is just to really show it.  Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gx1Lb2jf/4/  As you can see the vertical text is not pushing down into the div.

Here is the code out of fiddle:

```
    <div class="col-xs-12">

  <div class="col-xs-12 border-container">
      <div class="col-xs-1">
          <div class="vertical-text">dafadsf sda fd sf</div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-11">
     dfg dsfgdsfsg dsfg dsfg asdf sad gsdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf alkfhads lkfjhads lkfjhsadl kfjhaslkf   dfg dsfgdsfsg dsfg dsfg asdf sad gsdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf alkfhads lkfjhads lkfjhsadl kfjhaslkf   dfg dsfgdsfsg dsfg dsfg asdf sad gsdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf alkfhads lkfjhads lkfjhsadl kfjhaslkf  dfg dsfgdsfsg dsfg dsfg asdf sad gsdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf alkfhads lkfjhads lkfjhsadl kfjhaslkf
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

.vertical-text {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.border-container {border:2px solid #000}
.border{border:2px solid red}
.go-right{float:right}
.go-left{float:left}
.nopad{padding:0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer based on another question...  I changed it up a bit and here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/CCMyf/274/  hope it helps someone else.

```
Code on fiddle page above.
```